# Invalid Argument error when copying data from device to host

Tags: arrays, cuda, copy

I am having problems copying data from my device back to the host. My data are arranged in a struct:

```
typedef struct Array2D {
    double* arr;        
    int rows;       
    int cols;       
} Array2D;
```

`arr` is a 'flat' array. `rows` and `cols` describes the dimensions.

The code below shows how I am trying to copy the data back to the host:

```
h_output = (Array2D*) malloc(sizeof(Array2D));
cudaMemcpy(h_output, d_output, sizeof(Array2D), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
double* h_arr = (double*) malloc(h_output->cols*h_output->rows*sizeof(double));
cudaMemcpy(h_arr, h_output->arr, h_output->cols*h_output->rows*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
h_output->arr = h_arr;
```

However, in the fourth line the execution fails with cuda error 11 (invalid argument). I cannot see why this is happening. The size of the array is correct, and I can access both `h_output` and `h_array` from the host and both have 'real' addresses.

***EDIT***
Sorry for the late response to the request for more information (= more code).

I have tested that the pointer `d_output->arr` is a device pointer, by trying to access the value of the device pointer on the host. As expected, I was not allowed to do that leaving me with the thought that `d_output->arr` is in fact a valid device pointer.

The code's objective is to solve Thiele's differential equation using the fourth order Runge-Kutta method.

```
class CalculationSpecification
{

    /* FUNCTIONS OMITTED */

public:
    __device__ void RK4_n(CalculationSpecification* cs, CalcData data, Array2D* d_output)
    {
        double* rk4data = (double*)malloc((data.pdata->endYear - data.pdata->startYear + 1)*data.pdata->states*sizeof(double));

        /* CALCULATION STUFF HAPPENS HERE */

        // We know that rows = 51, cols = 1 and that rk4data contains 51 values as it should.
        // This was confirmed by using printf directly in this function.
        d_output->arr = rk4data;
        d_output->rows = data.pdata->endYear - data.pdata->startYear + 1;
        d_output->cols = data.pdata->states;
    }
};


class PureEndowment : CalculationSpecification
{
    /* FUNCTIONS OMITTED */

public:
    __device__ void Compute(Array2D *result, CalcData data)
    {
        RK4_n(this, data, result);
    }
};


__global__ void kernel2(Array2D *d_output)
{
    /* Other code that initializes 'cd'. */
    PureEndowment pe;
    pe.Compute(d_output,cd);
}


void prepareOutputSet(Array2D* h_output, Array2D* d_output, int count)
{
    h_output = (Array2D*) malloc(sizeof(Array2D));
    cudaMemcpy(h_output, d_output, sizeof(Array2D), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); // After this call I can read the correct values of row, col as well as the address of the pointer.
    double* h_arr = (double*) malloc(h_output->cols*h_output->rows*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(h_arr, h_output->arr, h_output->cols*h_output->rows*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)
    h_output->arr = h_arr;
}

int main()
{
    Array2D *h_output, *d_output;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_output, sizeof(Array2D));

    kernel2<<<1,1>>>(d_output);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    prepareOutputSet(h_output, d_output, 1);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

***EDIT2***

Additionally, I have now tested that the value of `d_output->arr` when running on the device is identical to the value of `h_output->arr` after the first `cudaMemcpy`-call in `prepareOutputSet`.

Comment: The most likely source of the error is `houtput->arr` not being a valid device pointer. Can you expand your code a little to show how you are allocating and copying the contents of `d_output` to the device?

Comment: `d_output` and its contents are allocated on the device using `malloc()`. I am sure that it contains actual data, as I tried printing the content of `d_output->arr` and got the expected output.

Comment: Do you mean `h_output` _and its contents_ ? Because `d_output` does not appear in your example code.

Comment: You can't copy from host to host using cudaMemcpy! You say d_output was allocated using malloc ? did you mean cuadMalloc ?

Comment: @ssnielsen Can you clarify if you are doing what talonmies is suggesting ?

Comment: @Pavan: Yes, `d_output` is allocated using malloc inside the kernel

Comment: @ssneilsen Can you please add that in the queston. There is a similar thread in cuda forums http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=222659 But looks like the issue is still unresolved.

Comment: @ssnielsen Correct me if I am wrong, doesnt nvcc also show which parameter is invalid ? If you can provide that information too, it may be useful.

Comment: @Pavan: More information is now added to the original question. 
I don't know whether or not nvcc is able to show the invalid parameter, I wouldn't know how to find out; to compile and run the code I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: @talonmies: Ooops, my bad, I put in some odd mixture of old and new code. Should be updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (copying device-allocated memory using cudaMemcpy) is a known limitation in CUDA 4.1.  A fix is in the works and will be released in a future version of the CUDA runtime.

Comment: @harrism: I got the same error code. On further investigation, I found that there was not enough RAM left to copy the data back to the CPU. Thus, `cudaMemcpy` was failing. Is this a valid reason for the error code or am I going the wrong way?

Comment: That's a different problem than described here.

Comment: Any idea as to when this limitation will be addressed? I have a project in development that would benefit greatly from the fix. Regards, James.

Comment: Currently there is no "fix" for this.  Given that it is 8 years later, my suggestion would be to check if the stated limitation is still present in [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#interoperability-host-memory-api).  If it is, there is no reason to assume a fix is available.  I can't make any future statements; check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is almost certainly caused by `h_output->arr` not being a valid device pointer, or by `h_output->rows` or `h_output->cols` having incorrect values somehow. You have chosen not to show any code explaining how the contents of the source memory `d_output` have been set, so it is not possible to say for sure what is the root cause of your problem.

To illustrate the point, here is a complete, runnable demo showing the posted code in action:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

inline void GPUassert(cudaError_t code, char * file, int line, bool Abort=true)
{
    if (code != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),file,line);
        if (Abort) exit(code);
    }       
}

#define GPUerrchk(ans) { GPUassert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

typedef float Real;

typedef struct Array2D {
    Real* arr;        
    int rows;       
    int cols;       
} Array2D;

__global__ void kernel(const int m, const int n, Real *lval, Array2D *output)
{
    lval[threadIdx.x] = 1.0f + threadIdx.x;
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        output->arr = lval;
        output->rows = m;
        output->cols = n;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const int m=8, n=8, mn=m*n;

    Array2D *d_output;
    Real *d_arr;
    GPUerrchk( cudaMalloc((void **)&d_arr,sizeof(Real)*size_t(mn)) ); 

    GPUerrchk( cudaMalloc((void **)&d_output, sizeof(Array2D)) );
    kernel<<<1,mn>>>(m,n,d_arr,d_output);
    GPUerrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );

    // This section of code is the same as the original question
    Array2D *h_output = (Array2D*)malloc(sizeof(Array2D));
    GPUerrchk( cudaMemcpy(h_output, d_output, sizeof(Array2D), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    size_t sz = size_t(h_output->rows*h_output->cols)*sizeof(Real);
    Real *h_arr = (Real*)malloc(sz);
    GPUerrchk( cudaMemcpy(h_arr, h_output->arr, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    for(int i=0; i<h_output->rows; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<h_output->cols; j++)
            fprintf(stdout,"(%d %d) %f\n", i, j, h_arr[j + i*h_output->rows]);

    return 0;
}
```

I have had to take a few liberties here, because I only have a compute capability 1.2 device at my disposal, so no device side `malloc` and no double precision. But the host side API calls which retrieve a valid `Array2D` structure from device memory and use its contents are effectively the same. Running the program works as expected:

```
$ nvcc -Xptxas="-v" -arch=sm_12 Array2D.cu 
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kerneliiPfP7Array2D' for 'sm_12'
ptxas info    : Used 2 registers, 16+16 bytes smem

$ cuda-memcheck ./a.out 
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
(0 0) 1.000000
(0 1) 2.000000
(0 2) 3.000000
(0 3) 4.000000
(0 4) 5.000000
(0 5) 6.000000
(0 6) 7.000000
(0 7) 8.000000
(1 0) 9.000000
(1 1) 10.000000
(1 2) 11.000000
(1 3) 12.000000
(1 4) 13.000000
(1 5) 14.000000
(1 6) 15.000000
(1 7) 16.000000
(2 0) 17.000000
(2 1) 18.000000
(2 2) 19.000000
(2 3) 20.000000
(2 4) 21.000000
(2 5) 22.000000
(2 6) 23.000000
(2 7) 24.000000
(3 0) 25.000000
(3 1) 26.000000
(3 2) 27.000000
(3 3) 28.000000
(3 4) 29.000000
(3 5) 30.000000
(3 6) 31.000000
(3 7) 32.000000
(4 0) 33.000000
(4 1) 34.000000
(4 2) 35.000000
(4 3) 36.000000
(4 4) 37.000000
(4 5) 38.000000
(4 6) 39.000000
(4 7) 40.000000
(5 0) 41.000000
(5 1) 42.000000
(5 2) 43.000000
(5 3) 44.000000
(5 4) 45.000000
(5 5) 46.000000
(5 6) 47.000000
(5 7) 48.000000
(6 0) 49.000000
(6 1) 50.000000
(6 2) 51.000000
(6 3) 52.000000
(6 4) 53.000000
(6 5) 54.000000
(6 6) 55.000000
(6 7) 56.000000
(7 0) 57.000000
(7 1) 58.000000
(7 2) 59.000000
(7 3) 60.000000
(7 4) 61.000000
(7 5) 62.000000
(7 6) 63.000000
(7 7) 64.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

Comment: The original question is now updated with more code. Hopefully it sheds some light over the problem.

Comment: That extra code you have posted doesn't change the conclusion of this answer - it clearly shows that if the pointer in question is a valid device pointer, the original API code you posted works corrected. The real question is why is your device malloced pointer is invalid by the time it is returned the to host.

Answer (score 0):

I tried allocating the pointer `Array2D->arr` on the host using cudaMalloc instead of allocating it on the device using malloc. After that, the code works as intended.

It looks very much like the problem described in the thread (http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=222659) on nVidia's forum that Pavan referred to in the comments to the question.

I think that probably closes the question for now, as the code works fine. However, if anyone has a proposal for a solution which utilizes malloc on the device, feel free to post.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `h_output` is allocated with a call to `malloc()`.  In the first call to `cudaMemcpy()` (line 2), `h_output` is being used as as a host pointer (which seems right).  In the second call to `cudaMemcpy()` (line 4), `h_output->arr` is being used as a device pointer (which does not seem right).  In that 4th line, it looks like you are copying from host memory to host memory.  So, you will probably want to use just a straight `memcpy()` instead of `cudaMemcpy()`.

At least that is what it looks like from the code you have provided.

Comment: That isn't really what the code is doing at all. It should be perfectly fine, but *only* if `h_output->arr` (and by extension `d_output->arr` which is the source memory) hold valid device pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  `h_output` is allocated with `malloc()`.  Then `cudaMemcpy()` is used to copy into it using it as a host pointer.  Then (without setting `h_output->arr` other than what it was set to from the previous call to `cudaMemcpy()`) `cudaMemcpy()` is called again using `h_output->arr` as a device pointer.  And it seems that you make a comment to that effect around the question.

Comment: After the `cudaMemcpy()` call, `h_output` effectively points to a copy of the device memory structure that `d_output` pointed to. If `d_output->arr` was a valid device pointer, so is `h_output->arr` after the copy.

Comment: Tricky! I didn't know that was possible.  Fair enough then.  Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say it was "tricky". More like "pointer indirection 101" : don't just think about what memory space a given pointer is in, think about what is contained in the memory it points to.